# Complicated 'double' contextual and relationships view

Tags: views

I would like some help on how to implement the following view:
A block that shows all the '**events**' happening at any '**location**' created by a user.

I have 'event' and 'location' content types. There is a field in the 'event' node which refers to a 'location' node (it's nid).

I am familiar with views, just not sure how to get the 'double filtering' required to show only events that have a location that is created by the user logged in. I cannot create an 'author' relationship to a contextual filter for the location or event to a simple filter, as the view displays events, not locations... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Argiepiano for the direction to take. Here is what I ended up doing. Quick reminder of the objective:
a business owner (owning more than one places) wants to view all **events** created at any of his **locations**. **Locations** and **events** are separate content types and in the '**event**' content type, there is an *entity reference field* to the **location** nodes.

1. Create a view of content type **EVENT**.
2. Create a relationship '`Entity Reference: Referenced Entity`'. Call it 'location node'.
3. Create a relationship '`Content Author`'. Call it 'location author'. Add a relationship to 'location node'.
4. Create a contextual filter '`Content: Author uid`'. Add a relationship to 'location author'.
5. In that filter, in the section 'WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL', select '`provide default value`' and choose '`User ID from logged in user`'.

I hope it helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a View of the Content Type **Location** (these are the nodes created by your users, right?).

1. Create a Relationship to **Author**.
2. Create a Filter to `user: current` and select Yes in `Is the logged in user` (NB: this a a regular filter, not a Contextual Filter)
3. Create a Relationship to the **Event** type through its reference field to Location (**NB:** select `Entity Reference: Referencing Entity` . If you select "Require this relationship" the View will limit the **Location** types to only those referenced in an **Event** node
4. Add any field to the View, but be sure to select the relationship you created in 3 above to show field from the Event type

That's it! Nice question!

Comment: Hi Argie, will that not create a list of locations, and not events? I am interested in a list of 'events' for which location fields are referring to the 'location' nodes created by the logged in user. Imagine a restaurant owner wanting the list of all events happening at his restaurants.